# how to use \href or \ref for creating a link within the document

Tags: cross-referencing, ref, href, cross-platform

I would like that when I click the word 'universe' in the following MWE, it takes me to Fig of duck.

How can that be done?

```
 \documentclass[]{report}
 \usepackage[]{graphicx}
 \usepackage{chngcntr}
 \usepackage{hyperref}
 \begin{document}
 And, when you want something, all the \href{fig:duck1}{Universe} conspires in helping you to achieve it.
 \newpage
 \begin{figure}[!h]
 \includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{example-fig-duck}%
 \caption{duck1}
 \label{fig:duck1}%
 \end{figure}% <<<

 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
\hyperref[fig:duck1]{Universe}
```

to link a word to a label.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
And, when you want something, all the \hyperref[fig:duck1]{Universe} conspires in helping you to achieve it.

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
\caption{duck1}
\label{fig:duck1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: The word "Universe" is a hyperlink.]

Comment: downvote for showing the duckish output:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ohhh ... rubbish, I removed the `\newpage` on purpose to have the duck on the same page so I can harvest all the reputation off it.

Comment: Haha @David , the ultimate answer perhaps is not 42, but this duck :-)